# Web Scraping loop structure issues

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm currently writing some code to web scrape from AutoTrader as a practice project. I'm having trouble printing the results I need.

The desired output should be:

```
Car 1
Specs Car 1
```

Instead, it's

```
Car 1
Specs Car 1
Specs Car 2
Specs Car X

car 2
```

Where in my looping structure am I going wrong?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests

page_link = ("https://www.autotrader.co.uk/car-search?sort=price-asc&radius=1500&postcode=lu15jq&onesearchad=Used&onesearchad=Nearly%20New&onesearchad=New&make=AUDI&model=A5&price-to=8500&year-from=2008&maximum-mileage=90000&transmission=Automatic&exclude-writeoff-categories=on")
LN = 0
r = requests.get(page_link)
c = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")

all = soup.find_all("h2",{"class":"listing-title title-wrap"})
all2 = soup.find_all('ul',{"class" :'listing-key-specs '})
```

The above block of code is fine. The below block prints the outputs.

```
LN = -1
ListTotal = len(all)
for item in all:
    if LN <= ListTotal:
        LN += 1
        print(item.find("a", {"class": "js-click-handler listing-fpa-link"}).text)
        for carspecs in all2:
            print (carspecs.text)
    else:
        break
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're printing every `carspec in all2` every time

```
all = ...
all2 = ...

for item in all:
    ...
    for carspecs in all2:  
            # will print everything in all2 on each iteration of all
            print (carspecs.text)
```

I suspect you want

```
for item, specs in zip(all, all2):
    ...
    print(specs.text)
```

---

Just FYI I cleaned up you code with better logic and names, got rid of superfluous stuff and made it obey the [python style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page_link = ("https://www.autotrader.co.uk/car-search?sort=price-asc&"
             "radius=1500&postcode=lu15jq&onesearchad=Used&"
             "onesearchad=Nearly%20New&onesearchad=New&make=AUDI&model=A5"
             "&price-to=8500&year-from=2008&maximum-mileage=90000"
             "&transmission=Automatic&exclude-writeoff-categories=on")

request = requests.get(page_link)
conn = request.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(conn, "html.parser")

# don't overload the inbuilt `all`
cars = soup.find_all("h2", {"class":"listing-title title-wrap"})
cars_specs = soup.find_all('ul', {"class" :'listing-key-specs '})

for car, specs in zip(cars, cars_specs):
    # your logic with regards to the `LN` variable did absolutely nothing
    print(car.find("a", {"class": "js-click-handler listing-fpa-link"}))
    print(specs.text)
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I just wanted to ask what you mean when you say overload the inbuilt all. What is the consequence of overloading?

Comment: @M.Ustun Python has a built-in [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#all) function. If you use `all` as a variable, you are redefining the function and changing it into a simple variable.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all  - if you overload it (really reassign in python jargon), you can no longer access this useful function